# Symfony 4 regroup choiceType-elements (radiobuttons) (via ViewTransformer)?

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button

For our local school, I'm building a form to manage the Parent-Teacher-Conference-Meetings. My structure at the moment is:

- A ParentTeacherConference has 1 or more days
- Such a Day can have one or more classes (ex 1A, 1B, 2A, ...)
- Each Class has several meetings (each 15min between an interval)

Giving 3 Consecutive collections OneToMany...

This structure works great in my Sonata-Admin Backend and everything is generated as it should. 
But I have a problem in the form the parents need to fill in.

As far as the layout, I need the same structure, conference->Days->Class->MeetingTimes.

Where the meetingTimes are a radiobutton, but these are **grouped by Day and Class** and I need them to be grouped by Class ONLY ! The parents that have a child in class 1A, need to select just 1 meetingTime for that class, not for multiple days...

I made 3 specific FormTypes, Conference->Day->Class, each using the next and the last being an EntityType that generates radiobuttons.
My final layout is correct in this way, but I can't seem to find a way to "regroup" the meeting radioButtons as they have a name-property that looks like "ptc[PTCDays][0][PTCClassrooms][0][PTCMeetings]" meaning they are grouped by day AND Classroom and they should be grouped by Classroom only, so that parents can only select 1 timeslot per class...

I've searched alot, but can't come up with a solution...
I need the full structure to generate the form-layout (displaying info on all entities Conference->Day->Class->Meeting) But the end-result I just need the selected Meetings in a ArrayCollection or something, but when you start with the full-entity, Symfony form repopulates the full entity when you submit the form.

What do you have to do to generate a full form based on a structured Entity, but get a simple form-output? The form layout is correct at the moment, but you have to select at minimum 1 meeting per class per day instead of 1 per class...

**Questions**:

- Is there a logical solution for this? The meetings should be visualy grouped by Day and by Class, but in the form they should be grouped by Class only...

I found the transformers, but don't know if they can be used for this?

- Can a ViewTransformer be used to transform the name-property of the radiobuttons? Couldn't find a single example of a ViewTransformer, only dataTransFormers...
- (Is the only solution to step away from Symfony Form-components? Generating the form (full layout) myself (just using twig, with my own radiobutton-names) and creating an unlinked Symfony Form to capture and validate the selection? Meaning Symfony Forms can't handle a situation like this one?)

Thanks for any and all help !!